# Can soft keyboard implementation determine its caller?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I'm thinking of creating a modified soft keyboard.

My question: is it possible to determine how the soft keyboard has been invoked? Can the soft keyboard implementation figure out that it came from an input field in the FooBarBaz app, or from an input field in a browser pointed to http://www.foobarbaz.com/whatever.html ?

Or is the soft keyboard completely agnostic, in that it only knows that input is required, and will send that input back to the caller without ever knowing who is the caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it would know, that would be a huge security risk. You can read more about Android's [Input Method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/).